# SQl if statement in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

How do I add the bottom line to my statement?

```
SELECT
AgentID,
PaymentAmount
FROM Table A

WHERE 
DATEOFPAYMENT 

GROUP BY 
CollectorNumber

ORDER BY 
CollectorNumber,
LastName,
DateofPayment,
PaymentAmount
```

---

> if DATEOFPAYMENT = yesterday then PaymentAmount else 0 as 'previous day'

or

> if DATEOFPAYMENT = current_Month then PaymentAmount else 0 as 'MTD'

or

> if DATEOFPAYMENT = current_Year then PaymentAmount else 0 as 'YTD

Comment: I don't understand where you'd like to put those. You can use `CASE` instead of `IF`, but how you use it depends on what you're doing.

Comment: Have a look at the CASE statement. I thinking that'll help you. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Comment: Replace `DATEOFPAYMENT` in your `WHERE` with a `CASE` statement.

Answer (score 0):

We can study the [CASE syntax from here , it would be, *roughly* (I am not acquainted with MySQL date  formats , so please look that up )](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html)

```
SELECT AgentID, PaymentAmount FROM Table A

WHERE CASE DATEOFPAYMENT 
 WHEN subdate(currentDate, 1)  THEN PaymentAmount  
 WHEN month() THEN PaymentAmount 
 WHEN year()  THEN PaymentAmount 
 ELSE 0
END

GROUP BY CollectorNumber

ORDER BY CollectorNumber, LastName, DateofPayment,
PaymentAmount
```

This is almost-done pseudo-code  , so please fix the syntax. But the case statement is like so.

Comment: @GoatCO - I know , just guiding him along

Comment: `ELSE` can occur but once, it should come after the last `WHEN..THEN`.  `AS` also doesn't belong in there.